# Laravel scope returns multiple elements when joining pivot-table

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have `vehicles` and `features`. Both tables are linked via the pivot-table `vehicles_features`.

Example-Table:

```
+------------+------------+
| vehicle_id | feature_id |
+------------+------------+
|          4 |         12 |
|          4 |         45 |
|          4 |         48 |
|          4 |         50 |
|          3 |          1 |
+------------+------------+
```

Now I have a dynamic scope on my Vehicle-Model which retrieves an array of feature-IDs:

```
public function scopeFeatures(Builder $query, array $topFeatureIds): Builder
{
    return $query
        ->join('vehicle_features_vehicles', function(JoinClause $join) use ($topFeatureIds){
            $join->on('vehicle_features_vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'view_vehicles_with_addresses.id')
                ->whereIn('vehicle_features_vehicles.vehicle_feature_id', $topFeatureIds);
        });
}
```

Unfortunately this returns the same vehicle four times when the given feature-ids are `[12, 45, 48, 50]`.

I think it's a problem with the type of join. How can I handle this?

Comment: why dont you declare the relation and use it to recover the features Ids ?

Comment: What do you mean? I need to have it as a scope because it is used in several places..

Comment: you have to have it as a relation, so you can use it anywhere you use those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using Joins was a little bit too much (in case of having the possibilities of Laravel's Eloquemt).

Like @N69S said, I've to use the relation defined on my model:

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(config('models.vehicles.feature'),
        'vehicle_features_vehicles',
        'vehicle_id',
        'vehicle_feature_id',
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

So I was able to create the following scope:

```
public function scopeTopFeatures(Builder $query, array $topFeatureIds): Builder
{
    return $query->whereHas('features', function(Builder $query) use ($topFeatureIds){
        $query->whereIn('vehicle_feature_id', $topFeatureIds);
    });
}
```

This scope is called like this in my Controller:

```
$query = VehicleView::available(); // available is also a scope defined on my model
if($request->has('topFeatures') && count($request->get('topFeatures')) !== 0){
    $query = $query->topFeatures($request->get('topFeatures'));
}
```